# render view in backbone.js + rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, render

I am trying to render the view "new_view.js.coffee" (a form to create users) on my root page. I am using the rails-backbone gem, so far I have this:

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<div id="container">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});
    newView.render();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

Its basically a copy of this (from the rails-backbone README.md):

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<div id="posts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Blog is the app name
    window.router = new Example.Routers.PostsRouter({posts: <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
```

My new view is this:

assets/javascripts/backbone/views/users/new_view.js.coffee

```
Example.Views.Users ||= {}

class Example.Views.Users.NewView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/users/new"]

  events:
    "submit #new-user": "save"

  constructor: (options) ->
    super(options)
    @model = new @collection.model()

    @model.bind("change:errors", () =>
      this.render()
    )

  save: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    @model.unset("errors")

    @collection.create(@model.toJSON(),
      success: (user) =>
        @model = user
        window.location.hash = "/#{@model.id}"

      error: (user, jqXHR) =>
        @model.set({errors: $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)})
    )

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))

    this.$("form").backboneLink(@model)

    return this
```

Here is my users router:

users_router.js.coffee

```
class Example.Routers.UsersRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @users = new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()
    @users.reset options.users

  routes:
    "new"      : "newUser"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newUser: ->
    @view = new Example.Views.Users.NewView(collection: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new Example.Views.Users.IndexView(users: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Example.Views.Users.ShowView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Example.Views.Users.EditView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)
```

The "new" template:

assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/users/new.jst.ejs

```
<h1>New user</h1>

<form id="new-user" name="user">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name"> name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<%= name %>" >
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="email"> email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<%= email %>" >
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Create User" />
  </div>

</form>

<a href="#/index">Back</a>
```

When I go to localhost:3000, all I see is "Loading..." (which I put in for the purpose of seeing whether or not the app starts). Again, how would I go about rendering the new_view in the #container div above?

Comment: You are not passing model `users` like in the example: `@posts`...

Comment: you mean "window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users}); vs. "window.router = new Example.Routers.PostsRouter({posts: <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe -%>});"? Should I pass the same kind of parameters to the view as I do with the router?

Comment: Yes. You should pass an @users.

Comment: so now i have `<div id="container">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({users: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    $('#container').html(newView.render());
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>`

Comment: still no luck with it

Answer (score 0):

You have not appended your rendered content to body:

```
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});
    $('body').html(newView.render().$el)
    // newView.render();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
```

Comment: i replaced "newView.render();" with your above line. I tried it as is...as well as changing the 'body' part to '#container' - still no luck. do i need both lines?

Comment: what do you mean by "review"?

Comment: you have to append the element belonging to view no view itself

Comment: element belonging to view: `$el` or `el`, view: `newView.render()`

Comment: tried: `$("#container").html(newView.render(el));`, `$(el).html(newView.render());`, and `$el.html(newView.render());` - still nothing, am I doing it right?

Comment: crud...i feel like an idiot - i tried... `$('#container').html(newView.render().$el);` and `$('body').html(newView.render().$el);` - the variable 'body' is supposed to be replaced by the container variable, correct?

Comment: and also....is this line right? `window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});` or do i need to pass something else? as in the posts example?

Comment: ok..i tried the new code...still nothing...i tried commenting in newView.render() too...dunno if im supposed to do that or not...regardless...it didn't work.

Comment: that's usually enough, but you have some thing weird there read carefully this http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor, paying attention to arguments.

Comment: print `console.log(newView.render().$el)` this should be your compiled template

Comment: ok...i got it...in firebug console i get: `ReferenceError: users is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});` what does that mean?

Comment: What I told you! `@users`.

Comment: hmmm...dont think so...changed it to `window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: @users});` and get `SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: @users});`