# ReferenceError: users is not defined rails + backbone + firebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, view, firebug, render

So I asked this question: [render view in backbone.js + rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717448/render-view-in-backbone-js-rails/)

I feel I have gotten close to the answer thanks to people pointing me in the right direction. The code in my app/views/home/index.html.erb:

```
<div id="container">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});
    //$('body').html(newView.render().$el)
    console.log(newView.render().$el)
    //newView.render();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

When I examine the firebug console after trying to load this page, I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: users is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code.

assets/javascripts/backbone/views/users/new_view.js.coffee

```
Example.Views.Users ||= {}

class Example.Views.Users.NewView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/users/new"]

  events:
    "submit #new-user": "save"

  constructor: (options) ->
    super(options)
    @model = new @collection.model()

    @model.bind("change:errors", () =>
      this.render()
    )

  save: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    @model.unset("errors")

    @collection.create(@model.toJSON(),
      success: (user) =>
        @model = user
        window.location.hash = "/#{@model.id}"

      error: (user, jqXHR) =>
        @model.set({errors: $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)})
    )

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))

    this.$("form").backboneLink(@model)

    return this
```

users_router.js.coffee

```
class Example.Routers.UsersRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @users = new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()
    @users.reset options.users

  routes:
    "new"      : "newUser"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newUser: ->
    @view = new Example.Views.Users.NewView(collection: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new Example.Views.Users.IndexView(users: @users)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Example.Views.Users.ShowView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    user = @users.get(id)

    @view = new Example.Views.Users.EditView(model: user)
    $("#users").html(@view.render().el)
```

Look at the comments to the old question, and you can pretty much see where I'm coming from - and what I have tried. Thanks!

UPDATE

user.js.coffee

```
class Example.Models.User extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'user'

  defaults:
    name: null
    email: null

class Example.Collections.UsersCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Example.Models.User
  url: '/users'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error said, users is not defined in `new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});`.

In your home_controller.rb you should have something like:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb:

```
...
window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool thanks! even closer now - here is what I have in the index.html.erb now: `<div id="container">Loading...</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
     $('body').html(newView.render().$el)
     Backbone.history.start();
   });
 </script>`

Comment: getting this error: `TypeError: this.collection is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

this.model = new this.collection.model();`

Comment: Where is defined `@collection`?

Comment: i think it is just in new_view.js.coffee?...or in the router?

Comment: do i need to declare @collection in my home controller?

Comment: is it defined here? `function NewView(options) {
var _this = this;
NewView.__super__.constructor.call(this, options);
this.model = new this.collection.model();
this.model.bind("change:errors", function() {
return _this.render();
});
} `?

Comment: Do you have backbone models and collections?

Comment: i have the models...not sure about collections - im using the rails-backbone gem to integrate with rails

Comment: this is from the router? looks like something with a collection is happening here...`class Example.Routers.UsersRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @users = new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()
    @users.reset options.users`

Comment: my users model: `class Example.Models.User extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'user'

  defaults:
    name: null
    email: null

class Example.Collections.UsersCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Example.Models.User
  url: '/users'
`

Comment: where do i define @collection?

Comment: what is the url when this erorr is coming ?

Comment: just the root page localhost:3000

Comment: I have paste answer. hope that would be useful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating `NewView` object at initial stage when page loads.  `window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});` When it goes to NewView cosutructor it would not find the `@collection` because you are not passing in the parameter of `NewView`.

You should initialize the router when page load and then start backbone history as per the standard example of Backbone in Rails. I have an [Example in Github](https://github.com/sonianand11/backboneJs_example) which works fine. Please take a look of it and follow some documentation of backbone. If you want to make it working then you can put `window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users,collection: <CollectionObject>});`

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: i dont understand where the <CollectionObject> would come from...or where it is defined

Comment: should i leave the line that starts with "window.router" from the scaffolding of rails-backbone on the index page?

Comment: <CollectionObject> would be your backbonjs user collection object. i.e.Example.Collections.UsersCollection. You should write like this : window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users,collection: new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()});

Comment: did this: `window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>,collection: new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()});` now i am getting an error that says `TypeError: Backbone.history is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

Backbone.history.start();` also...i cant do "model: users" - it doesnt work...it throws the error `ReferenceError: users is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: users});`

Comment: Ok...i made a breakthrough...the view is now displayed now - i had some syntax errors...but im still getting the error `TypeError: Backbone.history is undefined [Break On This Error] Backbone.history.start();`

Comment: btw...the site seems to work - it creates a user...just doesnt redirect to the show page once the user is created (i may have to do that myself)...but if i go to the show page directly it works...so does destroying users and such

Comment: is this happening because i need to create a router as well?

Comment: im going to start a new question..im almost there!

Comment: You should really understand how backbone is working in Rails. Please follow the example I have given of Github so that you will get some idea that how it should work. And If my answer was useful then please give some votes to it :-)