# backbone.js + rails + firebug TypeError: this.model is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, firebug, router, typeerror

Ok guys, I originally set out to render the users' NewView onto my root page. I have gotten to the point where I can see the form, but when I fill it out and click "Create User" I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.model is undefined

$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Here is the relevant code:

index.html.erb

```
<div id="container">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>,collection: new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()});
    window.router = new Example.Routers.UsersRouter({users: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    $('body').html(newView.render().$el);
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

Here is one question I posted today which has brought me to this question...reading the comments should be helpful!

[ReferenceError: users is not defined rails + backbone + firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719941/referenceerror-users-is-not-defined-rails-backbone-firebug)

I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that I created two windows? "window.newView" and "window.router".

There needs to be a router for Backbone.history.start() to work...correct? This is why I added the router line in the first place...because I was getting an error with Backbone.history.start().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works, I passed "pushState: true" to the start method...does not throw any errors at least...and I can go through and sign up, show, and destroy a user...it doesnt redirect to the show page once the user is created when being created on the index page though.

```
<div id="container">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.newView = new Example.Views.Users.NewView({model: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>,collection: new Example.Collections.UsersCollection()});
    window.router = new Example.Routers.UsersRouter({users: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    $('body').html(newView.render().$el);
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  });
</script>
```

Please correct me if there is anything screwy with my fix.